# Rspec 2 - name of class inside of tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec, rspec2

I have next html code:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="/users/page">Page</a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I want to make sure that i have li tag with class "active" and inside of that text.

So, i tried that:

```
response.should have_selector( "li", :class => "active" ,:content => "Page")
```

And it doesn't work, i get such error:

```
Failure/Error: response.should have_selector( "li", :class => "active" ,:content => "Page")
       expected following output to contain a <li class='active'>Page</li> tag:
```

How can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it:

```
response.body.should have_selector( "li.active") do
   have_selector('a', :content => 'Pages')
end
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you can add the class to the css selector.  Something like:

```
response.body.should have_selector( "li.active", :content => 'Page')
```

Answer (score 0):

We've had similar issues with Watir testing in that the :class matcher is an exact string match; not like a CSS class selector at all.

Our workaround was to switch to an xpath selector, e.g.:

```
response.should have_selector("li", :xpath => 'contains(@class, "active")')
```

A caveat: I have not had a chance to test the above code; I'm just showing how we've used 'contains' against the @class attribute to match partial class strings.